# Modify excel cell

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, openxml, epplus

Good morning,
I would like to edit some cells from already existing excell file. I tried use EPPlus and normal OpenXml classes. However I failed. In both situation program won't crash but always return old (not modified) excel. Please, what am I doing wrong?

Trial 1 - EPPlus:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"Path\Test.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}

using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))
{
    ExcelWorkbook excelWorkBook = excelPackage.Workbook;
    ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets.First();
    excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Test";
    excelWorksheet.Cells[3, 2].Value = "Test2";
    excelWorksheet.Cells[3, 3].Value = "Test3";

    excelPackage.Save();
}

memoryStream.Position = 0;
return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/xlsx")
{
    FileDownloadName = "Tester.xlsx"
};
```

How i said it returns old excel. But in debug mode it contains new value also. It looks like memoryStream cannot be modified.

Trial 2 - OpenXml classes

```
Stream stream = System.IO.File.Open(@"Path\Test.xlsx", FileMode.Open);
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
{
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheet, "Sheet1");

    Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, "C", 3);
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue("Testos");
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
}

stream.Position = 0;

return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/xlsx")
{
    FileDownloadName = "Tester.xlsx"
};
```

And helper methods:

```
private static Row GetRow(Worksheet worksheet, uint rowIndex)
{
    Row row;
    if (worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).Count() != 0)
    {
        row = worksheet.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        row = new Row() { RowIndex = rowIndex };
        worksheet.Append(row);
    }
    return row;
}

private static Cell GetCell(Worksheet worksheet, string columnName, uint rowIndex)
{
    Row row = GetRow(worksheet, rowIndex);

    string cellReference = columnName + rowIndex;
    if (row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == columnName + rowIndex).Count() > 0)
    {
        return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == cellReference).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        Cell refCell = null;
        foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
        {
            if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellReference, true) > 0)
            {
                refCell = cell;
                break;
            }
        }

        Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference };
        row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);

        worksheet.Save();
        return newCell;
    }
}

private static WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPartByName(SpreadsheetDocument document, string sheetName)
{
    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName);

    string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
    return worksheetPart;
}
```

Once more thank you for help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem in both cases is that the modified workbook is not saved back to the stream:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"Path\Test.xlsx"))
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fs))
{
    ExcelWorkbook excelWorkBook = excelPackage.Workbook;
    ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets.First();
    excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Test";
    excelWorksheet.Cells[3, 2].Value = "Test2";
    excelWorksheet.Cells[3, 3].Value = "Test3";

    excelPackage.SaveAs(ms); // This is the important part.
}

ms.Position = 0;
return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/xlsx")
{
    FileDownloadName = "Tester.xlsx"
};
```

Answer (score 10):

although this is answered I'll add from my experience.

It is easier to open the ExcelPackage from FileInfo instead of Stream, then saving becomes simpler.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
        {
            ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
            ExcelWorksheet currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.SingleOrDefault(w =>  w.Name == "sheet1");

            int totalRows = currentWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            int totalCols = currentWorksheet.Dimension.End.Column;

            for (int i = 2; i <= totalRows; i++)
            {                   
                try
                {
                    currentWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = "AAA";

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Error(String.Format("Error: failed editing  excel. See details: {0}", ex));
                    return;
                }
            }

            package.Save();
```

Comment: Great package, but it comes with a licence tho.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Interop dll's from Microsoft to edit office documents http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx. Add the "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" to your solution. With this code i've changed 2 cell values.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Application excel = new Application();

        Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Martijn\Documents\Test.xlsx", ReadOnly: false, Editable:true);
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Item[1] as Worksheet;
        if (worksheet == null)
            return;

        Range row1 = worksheet.Rows.Cells[1, 1];
        Range row2 = worksheet.Rows.Cells[2, 1];

        row1.Value = "Test100";
        row2.Value = "Test200";


        excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
        excel.Application.Quit();
        excel.Quit();
    }
```

I've started with Test1 and Test2 wich after the program running changed into the proper values.

[image: Situation before running code]
[image: Situation after running code]

Comment: It looks very good, can it works with streams? Becouse I need to edit local excel file and return it to download. (And streams becouse of possibility of multi-access (more users at time). Thanks.

Comment: With the Interop usage i don't think its possible to work with memory streams. As suggested by: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/623916/Load-excel-workbook-from-memory-stream consider to write the file in an temporary folder and then later return it to the user as an memory stream

Comment: What if there are 50 rows and want to alter 20 of them? I definitely can't use the above method  Range row1 = worksheet.Rows.Cells[1, 1]; Range row2 = worksheet.Rows.Cells[2, 1]; Can you give alternative to this for larger data values?

Answer (score 6):

I'm using [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) where updating a cell value is a no-brainer:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook("HelloWorld.xlsx"); // load the existing excel file
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Worksheet(1);
worksheet.Cell("A1").SetValue("Hello World!");
workbook.Save();
```

The NuGet package can be found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/).

Comment: Thanks for answer. However EPPlus can do it also. I forgot to say that I need have possibility to open and edit it by more users at time. Can it work with a stream - edit and return new version?
Becouse EPPlus can works with stream, but always returns old excel. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

//this help you to set cells in file excel : using System.Data.OleDb;

```
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/swtlist.xlsx;" +
                     @"Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;';Persist Security Info=False;";


        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            try
            {

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE  [Feuil1$]  SET d='yes' ", connection);

                  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate about your response

Comment: its simple i use OleDbCommand to send request to excel file ([Feuil1$] is name of sheet excel - d is name of colums ) then i use the ExecuteNonQuery to execute my request