# Updating the excelsheet using EPPlus in c#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a excel file which contains sheet named `Data`. This sheet already contains few data. I need to open this file and add more data in it. I have tried searching about this but everyone is just creating new sheets in their workbook. I need to update the current sheet. Below is my code:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"Path\File.xlsx")
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fs))
{
  ExcelWorkbook excelWorkBook = excelPackage.Workbook;
  ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets.First();
  excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Test";
  excelWorksheet.Cells[3, 2].Value = "Test2";
  excelWorksheet.Cells[3, 3].Value = "Test3";

  excelPackage.SaveAs(ms); 
}
```

but it didnt update the sheet. I do not what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me please. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are doing this:

1. Create a `MemoryStream` object in memory to store binary data.
2. Open file and read it into the `MemoryStream` object.
3. Create an `ExcelPackage` object based on the data in the `MemoryStream` object.
4. Make changes to the spreadsheet.
5. Save changes back to the `MemoryStream` object.

That's why the spreadsheet file does not get updated.

Use `FileInfo` and open the file directly with `ExcelPackage`:

```cs
// using System.IO;

FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"Path\File.xlsx");
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
  ExcelWorkbook excelWorkBook = excelPackage.Workbook;
  ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets.First();
  excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Test";
  excelWorksheet.Cells[3, 2].Value = "Test2";
  excelWorksheet.Cells[3, 3].Value = "Test3";

  excelPackage.Save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was actually following this first answer from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168657/modify-excel-cell).

Answer (score 2):

> Try this

```
var file = new FileInfo(path);

if (file .Exists)
{
    using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
    {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            ws.Cells[1,1].Value = "Test1";
            excelPackage.Save();              
    }    
}
```

Comment: I get a similar situation but with a file hosted on a sharepoint site :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62117472/write-to-excel-file-hosted-on-sharepoint-2016-using-epplus-c)

@Murat Gündeş : could you have a solution ?