# Populate data into an excel file and return as a response in WEB API (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

Is there any way we can populate data into excel in Web API (in .net 4.7 framework not .net core) and return the result in excel format as part of GET request?
I am totally new to this. please guide me regarding this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168657/modify-excel-cell)

Comment: The sample is using EPPlus and few are suggesting ClosedXML which are third party source. It seems EPPlus is having licensing. Is there any library from microsoft (Interop) which can be used for this purpose and return the response as a stream?

Comment: don't. let the API return the data itself, as it should and then the client can do whatever it wants with it.

Comment: that's true. We initially proposed the same where API returns data in json forma. But the client expects API to return well formatted, populated excel. That too without using any licensed third party libraries.